# how to open iMessage with some text message?

Tags: iphone, ios, imessage

This is how I open iMessage in my ipad app

```
NSString *stringURL = @"sms:";
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:stringURL];
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:url];
```

But what I want is open iMessage with some message i have text filed and i want to send its test to i message the way we do in mail like

```
 [mailViewController setMessageBody:textView.text isHTML:NO];
```

is there anything in iMessage by which I can open iMessage with test filed Message

thanks in advance

Comment: have you found the solution ? if yes then send me code.

Answer (score 3):

Very late response, but this was the first result I saw when trying to solve this problem and I wanted to provide my solution.

My reason for wishing to open the iMessage app and not use `MFMessageComposeViewController` was because `MFMessageComposeViewController` does not support iMessage apps. My goal was to prompt the user to open my iMessage app and the only way to do that is to open the iMessage app.

This can be done as follows (in Swift 2):

```
let phoneNumber = "9765432100"
let bodyText = "Hello World"

guard let messageURL = NSURL(string: "sms:\(phoneNumber)&body=\(bodyText)") else { return }
if UIApplication.sharedApplication().canOpenURL(messageURL) {
    UIApplication.sharedApplication().openURL(messageURL)
}
```

Some things to keep in mind:

1) You must add `sms:` to `LSApplicationQueriesSchemes` in your Info.plist

2) You can not open group messages in this manner.

3) Phone numbers must be formatted as follows: 9765432100. No spaces or extra characters, just the number

Answer (score -1):

You can not open iMessage with any URL. Messages.app will detect if the number has iMessage support and sent the message via iMessage.

When calling `sms:` URI you are just opening any app that will handle it, on a iPhone/iPad this will be the message app. The is the given number has an iMessage account the sms will be send via the iMessage network. If no account is found on the iPad you can not send the message.

if you wan the user to send an SMS message from within your app you should use [`MFMessageComposeViewController`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/MessageUI/Reference/MFMessageComposeViewController_class/Reference/Reference.html).

Like:

```
// Fist check if we can send messages
if ([MFMessageComposeViewController canSendText] {
   MFMessageComposeViewController *composer = [MFMessageComposeViewController new];
   composer.body = @"Your message goes here";
   // Then present the composer in a UIPopoverController.
}
```

Comment: no i need to open iMessage and so far i am able to open it with above code so you saying i can not open it with some text message ?

Comment: iMessage app get launched by that code but with blank text message filed i want to fill it with my text view text

Comment: the message will detect if the Number has what number you talking about sir